# jpos print image in NVRam

Tags: epson, javapos

I am developing a project with java for epson printer with jpos.
I set a bitmap in my code and I want to print the image that i set.
I can do it but i don't want to use the ASCII codes. Is there a function for it?

```
//here is set up my image
ptr.setBitmap(1, POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, "/temp/newimage.jpg",
                                 500, POSPrinterConst.PTR_BM_CENTER);
//here i am can print that image but i dont want to use that "\u001b|1B"
ptr.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, "\u001b|1B");
```

The reason why I don't want to use that ASCII code is because i will use different printer models so if I use the ASCII code maybe it will not work for another printer because the ASCII commands are different in every model or printer.

Comment: You probably want to tag this question as `javapos` instead of `jpos`, two totally different things.

Comment: comon guys.is there noone who knows that stuff?